# Windows multi-monitor with DisplayPort and icons rearranging

Tags: windows-10, display, power-management

I have three monitors connected: DisplayPort (main), monitor via HDMI, TV via HDMI (via integrated graphics card). As far as I can tell, I can't turn off the main monitor via monitor's power button or Windows will think the device disconnected and move everything on my Desktop to my secondary monitor. When this happens, I usually use DesktopOK to put the icons back.

My current workaround is to Power Options > Screen off and set it to "Never" when I'm using it and "1 minute" when I'm not so the screen turns off without being disconnected. This is somewhat tedious as I have to Windows X > Power Options ...

Alternatively, I have this script:

```
@echo off
powercfg /X -monitor-timeout-ac 0
pause
powercfg /X -monitor-timeout-ac 1
```

Which works but it spawns a cmd which is ugly, harder to distinguish in the taskbar, and can't be pinned so that it stands out. I've tried using Bat2Exe but it has the same issue.

I've heard about a device you can connect DP and it'll be always on but I don't want to get an extra connector.

Does anyone have any recommendation for the DP issue or maybe wrapping the script up nicely (maybe JAR)?

Comment: Why do you need the pause? Without that, the cmd window should do away. Have one script for 0 and another for 1 and use each as needed rather than having the pause have one of each and be done with it. Make a shortcut to each and name each accordingly and then right click and pin to taskbar so you need only to click whichever is needed as-needed with no lingering cmd window due to the pause command.

Comment: The pause is so I can just use one script. The problem with two script is they open a cmd shell and windows will group them.